# Working with file c++

Tags: c++, file

I have a picture with the format .bmp , I want to add some text in the middle of the pic ! I know all of the seekp and seekg things , but when I use ios::app the text goes to end of the file , and any other thing I use , it discards all the text ! which ios:: ... I should use ?! Here is my code:

```
fstream file;
file.open ("mehdi.bmp" , ios::out | ios::binary | ios::ate);
char name[] = "Mehdi";
file.seekp (100);
file.write ((char*)name , sizeof (name));
```

Comment: Show us, what you have done so far...

Comment: Besides that writing "random" (for a ".bmp" file) data in the middle of the file, using open mode `ios::out` will _overwrite_ the file you try to open.

Comment: So what should I do for this not happen ?! @JoachimPileborg

Comment: To not overwrite the file, use also the `ios::in` flag, so you have `ios::in | ios::out`. And learn the format of the file, or you will destroy it.

Comment: Tnx a lot ! :) @JoachimPileborg

Comment: You can not add text to a bmp by appending the text at some random location in the image bits. That will certainly not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest would probably be to read in all the text into a string, or a vector of lines, and then modify the string/vector, and write it out again.

Comment: I can't do that because it is a picture and its too big !

Comment: @Mehdi Then your description in your question is wrong, you don't have a file with some text in it. You can't simply write some random text in the middle of a file with special format, and expect it to work okay.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, it seems that you want to produce an image with a drawing of a text displayed somewhere in the picture, not a file containing the bytes of the characters of a string.

If this is the case, you should use some drawing libraries that will draw a text somewhere in the picture using a font and a color.